# Hyperledger Fabric CA - Storing the identity materials the correct way

Tags: certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Currently I have a VM running and installed the binaries needed for fabric-ca. I have a docker-compose file looking like this:

[image]

I have some questions regarding this:

- the docker-compose file will create one container, if I want it for
  more organizations, do I need to copy/paste this and change the port
  number? (I don't want to use intermediate CAs).
- When registering/enrolling an identity, it will override the default
  materials because It will always put the materials from the new identity in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-client. So when creating multiple
  identities (orderer, peers, users etc..) how do I need to organize
  them? What's the best practise?
- In the image you can see that the server and clients are specified,
  is this a good approach? Or should the client and the server be a
  different container?

Answer (score 0):

**More than one CA in a Docker Compose file** - you can look at the [Build your first network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) tutorial in the Fabric Docs which has a 2 Org network and various configuration files including Docker Compose.

**Combined client/server Container** - This might be convenient for testing, but in a production scenario definitely not for Security and Operational Integrity reasons.

**Overwriting Identities** - the enroll command writes a tree of data to the location specified by the environment variable `FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME` but you can use `--home` to redirect the tree to a different location:

`fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://Jane:janepw@myca.example.com:7054 --home /home/test/Jane/`